# Put a <label> and <input type="text"> tag in the same row

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to create a `<form>` as part of a project, which has text inputs with a label before them. I am trying to put the `<label>` and the `<input>` on the same line, aligned to the right side like this example project:

[image: correct result]

Here is the code I have attempted to use:

```css
.labelrow {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.inputrow {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form">
  <div class="labelrow">
    <label id="name" for="name">* Name:</label></div>
  <div class="inputrow">
    <input type="text" id="name" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your name"></div>

  <div class="labelrow">
    <label id="email" for="email">* Email:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputrow">
    <input type="email" id="name" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your email">
  </div>
</form>
```

This code gives me the result of this:

[image: my result]

The `<label>` are aligned correctly, but the `<input>` are on the other line. What can I fix to get both on the same line and aligned to the right like the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

- House both label and input into a single `div`
- Add `display: flex` to the parent so you can have more flexibility styling your fields on small screens. For example, you could move the label above the input on small screens when viewport space is limited using `flex-direction: column`
- `label`s typically don't have `id`s. Instead, they point to `form` elements containing `id`s. I've fixed your `label`s in the following code
- Duplicate `id`s are a no-no as well (also fixed)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.input-field {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="name">* Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your name">    
    </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="email">* Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your email">    
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

By enclosing both elements into the same "div" you can align them together in a row.

```
<form id="survey-form">
    <div class="inputrow">   
        <label id="name" for="name">* Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your name">
    </div>
    <div class="inputrow">   
        <label id="email" for="email">* Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="name" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
</form>
```

By default, "div" tags always place a line break before and after they're inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<div>s` and add a `<br>` after each `<input>`. Add the following to both `<label>` and `<input>`:

> ```
> display: inline-block;
> height: 1.2rem; 
> line-height: 1.2rem;
> vertical-align: middle;
> ```

`height` and `line-height` can be adjusted but keep them equal to each other. Set `<form>` width to 100vw and of course `text-align: right` on `<label>s`. Place the `<label>s` and `<input>s` into a `<fieldset>` and assign the following to the `<fieldset>`

> ```
> width: 50vw;
> margin-left: 40vw;
> border: 0px none transparent
> ```

BTW the `<label>s` have a duplicate `#id` which is invalid, therefore removed.

---

### Demo

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.2 Raleway;
  background: #FBFBFB;
}

form {
  width: 70vw;
}

fieldset {
  width: 50vw;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  border: 0px none transparent;
  background: none;
}

legend {
  width: 70vw;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label,
input,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font: inherit;
}

input {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

label {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
}

button {
  height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  float: right;
  cursor:pointer;
}

sup {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 70%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<form id="survey-form">

  <fieldset>
  
    <legend>Let us know how we can improve freeCodeCamp</legend>

    <label for="name">* Name:</label>

    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required><br>

    <label for="email">* Email:</label>

    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required><br>

    <label for="age">* Age:</label>

    <input id="age" type="number" placeholder="Enter your age" min='18' max='120' required><br>

    <sup>* Required</sup>
    
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>

  </fieldset>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Potentially the simplest option is to put the `input` inside the `label`. Make the `label` a block item with text align right.

```css
label {
  display:block;
  text-align:right;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form">
  
    <label id="name" for="name">* Name: <input type="text" id="name" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your name"></label>
    <label id="email" for="email">* Email: <input type="email" id="name" class="input-field" required placeholder="Enter your email"></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap each in their own `div` you get the stacking that you are seeing.  Put both the `label` and the `input` into a single `div`.